# share article into facebook from joomla module

Tags: facebook, joomla

i have module on joomla 1.5, this module content picture and it have link to article like this :

`<a href="www.cc.com/index.php?id-22"><img src="....></a>`

so i need when user click on this picture share article on `<a href="www.cc.com/index.php?id-22"><img src="....></a>` to facebook.

Answer (score 0):

I would like you to make use of Facebook Graph API

Refer the below mentioned link for better understang
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/facebook-api/

Download the PHP SDK from this link
https://github.com/facebook/php-sdk

Then there is a folder names "examples" which consists of 2 files
1.) example.php
2.) with_js_sdk.php

Inside both the files code like this at the top
// Create our Application instance (replace this with your appId and secret).

```
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => '103562503147391',
  'secret' => 'c753579eb3e805d0155fc5542c54260d',
));
```

You need to create your own APP from here https://developers.facebook.com/apps and get you own **appId** and **secret**.

The below mentioned code will post the link in you facebook wall

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright 2011 Facebook, Inc.
 *
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License"); you may
 * not use this file except in compliance with the License. You may obtain
 * a copy of the License at
 *
 *     http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT
 * WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied. See the
 * License for the specific language governing permissions and limitations
 * under the License.
 */

require '../src/facebook.php';

// Create our Application instance (replace this with your appId and secret).
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => 'APP_ID',
  'secret' => 'APP_SECRET',
));

// Get User ID
$user = $facebook->getUser();

// We may or may not have this data based on whether the user is logged in.
//
// If we have a $user id here, it means we know the user is logged into
// Facebook, but we don't know if the access token is valid. An access
// token is invalid if the user logged out of Facebook.

   if($user) {

      // We have a user ID, so probably a logged in user.
      // If not, we'll get an exception, which we handle below.
      try {
        $ret_obj = $facebook->api('/me/feed', 'POST',
                                    array(
                                      'link' => 'www.example.com',
                                      'message' => 'Posting with the PHP SDK!'
                                 ));
        echo '<pre>Post ID: ' . $ret_obj['id'] . '</pre>';

      } catch(FacebookApiException $e) {
        // If the user is logged out, you can have a 
        // user ID even though the access token is invalid.
        // In this case, we'll get an exception, so we'll
        // just ask the user to login again here.
        $login_url = $facebook->getLoginUrl( array(
                       'scope' => 'publish_stream'
                       )); 
        echo 'Please <a href="' . $login_url . '">login.</a>';
        error_log($e->getType());
        error_log($e->getMessage());
      }   
      // Give the user a logout link 
      echo '<br /><a href="' . $facebook->getLogoutUrl() . '">logout</a>';
    } else {

      // No user, so print a link for the user to login
      // To post to a user's wall, we need publish_stream permission
      // We'll use the current URL as the redirect_uri, so we don't
      // need to specify it here.
      $login_url = $facebook->getLoginUrl( array( 'scope' => 'publish_stream' ) );
      echo 'Please <a href="' . $login_url . '">login.</a>';

    } 

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

After connecting your site to Facebook you can this onclick event to your image link =>

```
onclick="FB.ui({method: 'stream.share', display:'button', u: 'http://www.cc.com/index.php?id-22' }, null);"
```